# Browser Output using fread()

Tags: php, fread

I am new to PHP and was just trying to write and then read a html file with following code:

```
<?php 
 #Aim: To open , write, save and close a file in PHP

 $fileName =  "myFile.html"; 

 $filePointer = fopen($fileName,"w+"); // Creating a file resource

 $html = '<html>
    <style>
        h1{color:#ee4e91;}
    </style>
    <body>
        <h1>This is some HTml that was written to the File using the 
        file pointer $filePointer in the file that is named as myFile</h1>
    </body>
   </html>
      '; // string to be written to the file in write+ mode*/

  write($filePointer,$html); // writing the string to the file
  fseek($filePointer,0);

  $content = fread($filePointer,filesize($fileName));

  header("Content-Length:".(string)filesize($fileName));
  header("Content-Type:text/html");

  echo $content;

  fclose($filePointer); // closing the file resource
 ?>
```

I can see the out in the console but fail in the browser. file_get_contents($fileName) and readfile($fileName) work fine .

What is the problem.How can I use fread() to output to the browser ?

Comment: whats the point of creating the file? you cna just echo the html diirectly

Comment: There's no function named `write()`. Change that to `fwrite()` and it should work fine.

Comment: Also [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/file_get_contents) and [`file_put_contents`](http://php.net/file_put_contents) often simplify things.